# Get the woocommerce orders in Asp.net MVC

Tags: woocommerce

WooCommerce.NET: 0.730, vs2017, .netframework 4.5.1
I want to implement get orders function. below the code:

```
public class MyRestAPI : RestAPI
    {
        public MyRestAPI(string url, string key, string secret, bool authorizedHeader = true,
            Func<string, string> jsonSerializeFilter = null,
            Func<string, string> jsonDeserializeFilter = null,
            Action<HttpWebRequest> requestFilter = null) : base(url, key, secret, authorizedHeader, jsonSerializeFilter, jsonDeserializeFilter, requestFilter)
        {
        }
        public override T DeserializeJSon<T>(string jsonString)
        {
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(jsonString);
        }
        public override string SerializeJSon<T>(T t)
        {
            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(t);
        }
    }
```

and

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index(string shopUrl)
        {
            string endPoint = "/wp-json/wc/v2/";

            MyRestAPI rest = new MyRestAPI(shopUrl+endPoint, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("WooAccessKey"), ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("WooSecretKey"));
            WCObject wc = new WCObject(rest);

            //Get all orders
            var orders = await wc.Order.GetAll();

            return View();
        }
```

But it show the error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1sxw.png)

I don't know why. This is the simplest project. it only get orders. No other plugins and customized code. Is there a logic error in my code? When debug this line and next step:

```
var orders = await wc.Order.GetAll();
```

The error showed up.